# How do I manually execute a key combo from a Vim script file?

Tags: vim

Say I want to run the key combo `<C-e>` five times from a Vim script. Is that possible? If so, how is it done?

---

Specifically, I need this because I want to map a key to nudge the viewport one fourth of the screen height in a direction. For that I need to combine the function `winheight(".")` with the key combo `<C-e>` somehow.

**Note:**  I know I can change the option `'scroll'` to set the number of lines `<C-u>` and `<C-d>` scroll, but that key combo also moves the cursor. Additionally, I don't know how to set the `'scroll'` option to scroll a portion of the window height, except that it scrolls half the window height when I set it to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple commands, `:norm[al][!]` is sufficient. For example, to yank a line:

```
norm! yy
```

For special characters, use `:exe[cute] "norm[al][!]"`. For example, to do `5<C-e>`:

```
exe "norm! 5\<C-e>"
```

With `exe`, other code can be inserted by using multiple arguments:

```
exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 "\<C-e>"
```

However, arguments are joined with spaces, which are then interpreted literally. To avoid this, use `.` to join arguments. Thus, for the desired effect:

```
exe "norm!" winheight(".")/4 . "\<C-e>"
```

See `:help norm` and `:help exe` for more information.

Comment: I was going to ask you, after your comment, why I had to use `execute` for it to work. I see you were way ahead of me :)

Comment: For anyone interested, you can find the doc on escaping special keys using ``\`` on `:h expr-quote` inside Vim.